# beq assembly MIPS

Tags: assembly

I'm so confused about beq function in assembly MIPS.
Lets assume I have `beq $t1 $t2 60` , so it would be mapped as I type function. so we could say for example assuming that beq mapped to

> 100100 , $t1=5 , $t2=4, and immediate 60

so the block of IP type instruction is:

> 100100 | 5 | 4 | 60

but what's confused me that beq means if $t1 = $t2 then it would jump 60 steps from the offset PC ..
so the I type instruction should be mapped to 
100100 | 5 | 5 | 60
so the implementation mapping of registers should be 5 and 5 .. not 5 and 4 , am I right? because `beq` means `$t1=$t2` ...so must the mapping instruction of registers of that instruction must be

> 100100 | 5 | 5 | 60 and not
>   100100 | 5 | 4 | 60

so what should that instruction mapped?

> to 100100 | 5 | 4 | 60
>   or to 100100 | 5 | 5 | 60 ?

Comment: Why do you think "so the I type instruction should be mapped to 100100 | 5 | 5 | 60"?

Answer (score 1):

The numbers for `rs` and `rt` are the indexes of the GPRs to compare. The values stored in these registers are to be compared.

For your example with some exemplary values: If `R5` contains the value 23 and `R4` the value 42, the branch **will not** be taken. But if `R4` holds also the value 23, the branch **will** be taken.

*Note: Since I don't use MIPS regularly I might be wrong. But `100100` is the opcode for `lbu`, isn't it? I found `000100` as the opcode for `beq`.*